# Hadoop JobTracker memory usage increasingv

Tags: apache, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, data-analysis

When I open jobtrackerhost:50030/jobtracker.jsp

I can see the Heap Size like:
Cluster Summary (Heap Size is 1.17 GB/7.99 GB)

It's continue increasing. After 3-5 days, it grows to the peak.

We have 2 Hadoop clusters. 
On cluster A, the Heap Size stop increasing around the peak.
On cluster B, the heap size continue increasing, after 3-5 days, the jobtracker down. ( The process gone)

Now I really wonder to know why the heap size continue increasing? is it normal or is it a problem ?

Thanks,
Xinsong

Comment: Are there any jobs running? Please provide the cluster details (#machines, RAM per machine, #cores per machine) and the mapred-site.xml file that exists in $HADOOP_HOME/conf

Comment: Hi @vefthym , there are jobs continually running, but most of them will end in minutes~1hour, there are 10machines in the hadoop, RAM is 16G , CPU is 4cores,

Answer (score 0):

@vefthym, I think the mapred-site.xml file is not complete since the hadoop cluster is managed by Cloudera Manager.

Here is the content in the mapred-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--Autogenerated by Cloudera CM on 2013-07-01T01:39:46.361Z-->
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://xxxx.com:8020</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.file.buffer.size</name>
    <value>65536</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DeflateCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.Lz4Codec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.authentication</name>
    <value>simple</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.rpc.protection</name>
    <value>authentication</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.security.auth_to_local</name>
    <value>DEFAULT</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```